# Why does my terminal turn all text white?

Tags: macos, terminal, colors

When I launch terminal, it looks fine. Black text on a white background.
BUT when I run a command that requires the screen to scroll, it turns to white text on a white background. I have to triple-click to select-all in order to see the text. I use terminal all the time, so this is super annoying.
Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try piping your output through [less](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html).

```
$ command | less
```

You get the bonus of being able to page the output, and less might ignore the color control codes being sent by the program.

Comment: I can't do that because a build script runs the command, and the build is not interactive. Gotta just let it scroll. Plus, I need to see the output in case there are any errors. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: Piping through some sort of filter is the best approach when feasible. I don’t understand from the description why this wouldn’t be possible, *especially* because the build is not interactive. I would expect you to not be able to use a filter if the build *was* interactive. Other useful filtering commands for this are `cat -v` (which converts control characters into visible sequences of non-control characters) and `tee` to split the output so you can view it in the terminal and record it to a file, for example. Also, you could redirect to a file and view it in another terminal with `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

Try trashing the preferences file:

> com.Apple.Terminal.plist in Users//Library/Preferences

Also, can you give an example of a command that causes this behaviour?

Comment: Sadly, trashing the plist didn't help :( The command I run is actually a build script using Phing, a PHP port of Apache Ant. The command "phing propel" re-creates a bunch of files.

Comment: Ah, and is that the only command that causes this behaviour? Because if it is (for example, man ifconfig produces a lot of output in a similar fashion i'm willing to bet) then it means that Phing is causing wonky output. Have you consulted their support team?

Comment: man ifconfig produces nice black text on white background, but it doesn't scroll. The issue happens when the output causes the screen to scroll. That being said, I just tried: ls /*   and it stayed black. So I guess it is a Phing thing. Weird. Unfortunately, as with so much PHP stuff, Phing has no support team beyond a Google Group. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problems, I wish I could help further. I feel your pain regarding the PHP stuff. I haven't used Phing however.